# Android permissions not requested on installation

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've searched for similar questions before posting here and I didn't find a answer solving my issue.
My manifest.xml file seems correct, I'd like the user to be asked for permissions on installation (not runtime, it already works with my code). I don't know why the parameters I put doens't work:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="VILES" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="fr.nc.delegue.referendum" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

I use Cordova (and Quasar) to build my app, the app is working great, but I still have this problem of permissions not being requested on installation...
Can anyboy tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which api device you using for testing?

Comment: One of my real smartphones (the S9+ at the moment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, other than expecting something that is no longer available. Apps with a `targetSdkVersion` of `23` or higher operate purely off of runtime permissions — there is no way to force the Play Store or Android to prompt the user for permission at install time. And you cannot distribute your app on the Play Store (and on some other distribution channels) with that old of a `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand more what's happening. But then why on installation it's written "This application doesn't ask for any permission"? That is weird because when I run the app the permissions are asked for correctly.

Comment: @djcaesar9114: "But then why on installation it's written "This application doesn't ask for any permission"?" -- usually, the message is a bit different than that.

Comment: Actually the message is in French, so I translated in what I thought the message would be in English ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a try to add a Splash Activity (the first screen)  when you will ask for permission . 
When user first install app he will see a screen , let s say setup screen or introduction screen where he will be asked for permission. After you will set a property and won t show this screen again .

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your main activity, on create method.

```
/*all permision need for this app*/
        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        };


        /*check if the there is permission that is needed*/

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```