# Xamarin show permissions in installition screen

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions

How can I show permissions of my app in installation screen like in first Image:

Another App: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9bmu.png

My App: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC9lo.png

Comment: Do you add the permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`? And After Android 6.0, there are no this installation screen, all the permissions are granted at runtime. You can see this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60094559/android-permissions-not-requested-on-installation. Or you used custom Android OS, such as EMUI, If you used native android OS and Android 6.0 or later, no this installation screen.

Comment: @Leon Lu - MSFT my android version is 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Comment: I test Android 6.0, I cannot get the installaion screen, you can test it in native android OS.

Comment: @ Leon Lu - MSFT thanks for your answers, Could you look for this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414970/xamarin-set-custom-icon-for-shortcut

Comment: If you solve this issue by yourself, please share your answer.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I have changed `targetSdkVersion` as 22. It shows permissions on install screen but Package Installer stopping to work and when I click my app on launcher a Toast message is showed like "App didn't installed.".

Comment: edit2: @LeonLu-MSFT I have changed `targetSdkVersion` as 22. It shows permissions on install screen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `targetSdkVersion` as 22. It shows and auto grants permissions on installation screen :)